# Cancel an 'HttpClient' POST request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post, httpclient, cancellation

I am uploading an image with `HttpClient.PostAsync()` on my Windows Phone 8 app. The user has the option to cancel this upload via a UI button.

To cancel the POST request, I set a `CancellationToken`. But this doesn't work. After the cancellation request, I see still see the upload taking place in my proxy and it is evident that the request was ignored. My code:

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var file = new StreamContent(stream);
    file .Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        FileName =  "filename.jpg",
    };
    file.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
    content.Add(file);

    await httpclient.PostAsync(new Uri("myurl", UriKind.Absolute), content,
        cancellationToken);
}
```

Please also note that I have a `CancellationTokenSource` for the `CancellationToken`. After the user clicks on the Cancel button, `tokensource.Cancel()` is called. Also, the images in my testcase are from 1 to 2 MB (not that big).

So, is there a way to cancel an `HttpClient` POST request?

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29587505/1497596): *"There is no guarantee that cancelling the `CancelationTokenSource` will cancel the underlying operation. It depends upon the implementation of the underlying operation (in this case `SendAsync` method). Operation could be canceled immediately, or after few seconds, or never."* So, based on that, it appears that after making the `PostAsync()` request, you may need to check `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`, and if true, call `DeleteAsync()` on the uploaded image.

Comment: Though you specified [windows-phone-8](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-phone-8/info), you *didn't* specify whether you are using [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) or [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). (Based on the parameters provided to your `PostAsync()` call, it *appears* to be the latter.)

Comment: Related: [Properly Abort or Cancel PostAsync](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23920754/1497596)

Answer (score 4):

```cs
try
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(3000); // 3 seconds

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    await client.PostAsync(url, content, cts.Token);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // timeout has been hit
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would abort the underlying operation?

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a task doesn't terminate it instantly. You have to check manually before doing your work by checking the token's status:

```
if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) 
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

// Post request here...
```

This article is quite useful: [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I do that. My problem is, I want to cancel an upload who has already started (I see the upload traffic in my proxy). although my app stops the work and also the breakpoint on the httpclient response don't fire... the image is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

In implementations of HttpClient for Mono like in Xamarin, the get & post methods **don't honor the cancellation token if the host is not reachable**, and wait up to 2 minutes before failing. This is perhaps why CancellationTokenSource with a CancelAfter does not work here.

To fix this, the simplest method I found was using the Polly library  https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

```cs
var policy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000),
    TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic,
    (context, timespan, task) => throw new Exception("Cannot connect to server."));

await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    ...
});
```